# How to cross compile iw to Xilinx Petalinux?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, xilinx

### Update

The error happens at line 8962 of libtool, which performs a lot of commands inside a loop.  The content of the problematic command is

```
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -fPIC -DPIC genl/.libs/ctrl.o genl/.libs/family.o genl/.libs/genl.o genl/.libs/mngt.o -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib -lnl-3 -lpthread -lm -O2 -Wl,--version-script=../libnl.sym -Wl,-soname -Wl,libnl-genl-3.so.200 -o .libs/libnl-genl-3.so.200.19.0
```

If I manually run it, it says

```
error: genl/.libs/ctrl.o: No such file or directory
```

the .o s are there, but the problem is that make install is under sudo, but sudo is a different environment and it doesn't recognize the paths.  So solution is:

```
sudo -s
source /opt/pkg/......./settings.sh
```

source command is required by Xilinx Petalinux for the paths. Now make install will work

### Original

I am following the [beyond logic example](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_iw_wpa_supplicant_hostapd_rfkill_for_ARM) to cross compile the iw tool.  The first step is the libnl.  I am using CentOS to crossc compile libnl, so I have to run `source /opt/pkg/.../settings.sh` to setup the arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc paths.  I then used `./configure --host=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi`

The `make` is running fine.  But `make install` failed with following errors:

```
libtool: install: (cd /xxx/libnl-3.2.24/lib; /bin/sh /home/xxx/libnl-3.2.24/libtool  --silent --tag CC --mode=relink arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g -O2 -version-info 219:0:19 -Wl,--version-script=../libnl.sym -o libnl-genl-3.la -rpath /usr/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/lib genl/ctrl.lo genl/family.lo genl/genl.lo genl/mngt.lo libnl-3.la -lpthread -lm )
/xxx/libnl-3.2.24/libtool: line 8962: 
            arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
libtool: install: error: relink `libnl-genl-3.la' with the above command before installing it

make[3]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/xxx/libnl-3.2.24/lib'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/xxx/libnl-3.2.24/lib'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/xxx/libnl-3.2.24/lib'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

so since make is successful using `arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, why make install is complaining it can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with following statement

```
./configure --host=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi
```

`arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi` is not installed at /usr thats why getting  `arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found`error.

Install arm toolchain and then follow procedure mentioned in [beyond logic example](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_iw_wpa_supplicant_hostapd_rfkill_for_ARM)

Comment: Tried this: `./configure --host=arm-Xilinx-Linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/arm-Linux-gnueabi`, notice the difference and the error is still arm-Xilinx-Linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found.  --prefix tells where to install to, not hoping to find it for cross compile